# cordova.plugins.diagnostic plugin for Phonegap not installing

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am trying to add this [diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin) to my cordova app but when i try installing it and building a new application template with DevExpress it just fails with no real description of the error. I have done a fair amount of research on this plugin and have tried a few different ways to solve this error. I cant tell if it is the way the plugin is being referenced or something else in my config.xml file that is causing a clash and not allowing the diagnostic plugin to install. I am using VS 2013 to develop the app

Here is my config.xmf file. Can somebody look at it and see if they can find the problem? Any advice would help.

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.devexpress.apptemplate" version="1.0" versionCode="1">
<name>ApplicationTemplate</name>
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="adjustPan" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="60000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.1.0" />
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<!--value="cli-6.1.0"-->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
<gap:plugin name="com.devexpress.plugins.devextremeaddon" version="1.0.1" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="hu.dpal.phonegap.plugins.uniquedeviceid" spec="1.2.0" source="pgb" />

<gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" version="0.3.6" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.3.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" version="1.3.3" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.5.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="1.0.0" onload="true" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-ios-longpress-fix" version="1.1.0" source="npm" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.1.0" source="npm" onload="true" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" spec="0.9.0" source="pgb">
  <param name="APP_ID" value="550120638504769" />
  <param name="APP_NAME" value="Tradeway App" />
</gap:plugin>
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
<access origin="geo:*" launch-external="yes" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Did you tried installing this using Phonegap CLI?

Comment: Never used Phonegap CLI before. i am using DevExpress to install the plugins as it has a built in template builder that uses the Phonegap API. That checks the plugins and then installs them and creates an application template that it uses to build the APK file when it gets built.

Comment: The plugin page note says the following: Make sure your Cordova CLI version is 5.0.0+ (check with cordova -v). Cordova 4.x and below uses the now deprecated Cordova Plugin Registry as its plugin repository, so using a version of Cordova 4.x or below will result in installing an old version of this plugin  Are you sure, you are installing the latest version?

Comment: Yes, in the properties page of the project, it shows that cordova cli-6.1.0 is installed.

Comment: Are you using API 23? For API 22 and below, use cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22 plugin instead.

Comment: ok, it seems to be working now when i set the plugins version to 2.0.0. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You mean cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22? Shall i post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The official plugin page says, "**For users who wish to build against API 22 or below, there is a branch of the plugin repo which contains all the functionality except Android 6 runtime permissions. This removes the dependency on API 23 and will allow you to build against legacy API versions (22 and below).**

**The legacy branch is published to npm as cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22, so you'll need to use this plugin ID when adding it:**

```
cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22
```

Hence try adding cordova.plugins.diagnostic.api-22 instead of cordova.plugins.diagnostic if you are using API 22 or below. Hope it helps.

Comment: what i did was change the plugin from:    
     '<gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm"  />'
to:
    <gap:plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" source="npm" version="2.0.0" />
so it is using and older version of the plugin but it is working